# How do I count these comparisons in selection sort?

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
count = 0
def selectionSort(data):


    for index in range(len(data)):

        min = index
        count += 1
        # Find the index'th smallest element
        for scan in range(index + 1, len(data)):

            if (data[scan] < data[min]):

                min = scan

        if min != index: # swap the elements
            data[index], data[min] = data[min], data[index]

    return data

data = selectionSort([3,4,5,2,6])


print(count, data)
```

Comment: This should throw an exception. What exactly is happening? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It returns the right sorted list but my count says 0...

Comment: I am trying to count the comparisons being made.

Comment: You would get an exception; `UnboundLocalError` because you didn't mark `count` as a global.

Comment: `count` should either be defined within your function and returned alongside `data`, or be declared a `global`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code as-is should not run. You should get `local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`.

To fix this, add the following to the top of `selectionSort(data)`:

```
global count
```

A better way is to scrap the global variable and return `count` alongside the sorted data:

```
def selectionSort(data):
    count = 0
    for index in range(len(data)):
        min = index
        count += 1
        # Find the index'th smallest element
        for scan in range(index + 1, len(data)):
            if (data[scan] < data[min]):
                min = scan
        if min != index: # swap the elements
            data[index], data[min] = data[min], data[index]
    return count, data

count, data = selectionSort([3,4,5,2,6])
print(count, data)
```

Last but not least, you are counting something other than comparisons. I leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a local variable over a global as globals are almost always a bad idea in my experience.

Comment: Well where I placed the count+=1 was just a trial an error by me, thank you for the replies...I think i got it

Comment: This is what I have now